# Sed regex on part of a line

Tags: regex, sed

I am attempting to port javascript code to Java.  In so doing, I need to replace all of the single quoted strings with double-quoted strings.  This also requires me to replace the double-quotes with escaped double-quotes.  But I only want to escape the quotes within single-quote string blocks.

I can replace the quoted strings with no problem, using the following sed command:

```
sed "s/'\([^']*\)'/\"\1\"/g"
```

This successfully modifies the single-quoted strings to double-quoted strings.  But I still have to escape the internal double-quotes.  The easiest way would seem to be if sed provided a method by which to run a regex replacement on a section of a line.  But I do not know if that is possible.

Comment: You would need lookahead assertions to do this, and `sed` doesn't support those. Why does it have to be `sed`?

Comment: Could there also be escaped single quotes in the strings you're handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `sed` because its POSIX regex engine doesn't know lookaround. But it would be possible in (for example) a Python script, by splitting up the operation into two steps:

```py
import re
with open("myfile.js") as infile, open("myfile.jsconv", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
    line = line.sub(
        r"""(?x)"  # Match a double quote
        (?=        # only if it's followed by:
         (?:       # an even number of quotes, defined like this:
          (?:      # Either...
           \\.     # any escaped character
          |        # or
           [^'\\]  # a character except single quotes
          )*       # repeated as needed, followed by
         '         # a single quote.
          (?:\\.|[^'\\])*  # (Repeat this to ensure an even
          '        # number of quotes)
         )*        # Do this zero or more times.
         (?:\\.|[^'\\])* # Then match any remaining characters
         $         # until the end of the line.
        )          # End of loohahead""", 
        '\\"', line)
    line = re.sub(
        r"""(?x)' # Match a single quote
        (         # Match and capture
         (?:      # either...
          \\.     # an escaped character
         |        # or
          [^'\\]  # a character besides quotes or backslashes
         )*       # any number of times.
        )         # End of capturing group number 1
        '         # Match a single quote""", 
        r'"\1"', line)
    outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: ...and before someone complains that I should be compiling the regexes: Python does that and caches them automatically :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/'\''[^'\'']*'\''/!b;s//\n&\n/g;ba;:a;/\n\n/bb;s/\n['\'']/"\n/;ta;s/\n"/\\"\n/;ta;s/\n\([^'\''"]\+\)/\1\n/;ta;:b;s/\n\n//;ta' file
```

However, if quoted strings can be multiline, then a slightly different (but slower) approach is needed:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};/\x00/q1;s/'\''[^'\'']*'\''/\x00&\x00/g;bb;:b;/\x00\x00/bc;s/\x00['\'']/"\x00/;tb;s/\x00"/\\"\x00/;tb;s/\x00\([^'\''"]\+\)/\1\x00/;tb;:c;s/\x00\x00//;tb' file
```

This slurps the entire file into the pattern space then uses `\x00` as a marker to delimit the quoted strings. It checks first to see if `\x00` already exists in the file and bails out with exit code of `1` if it does, leaving the original file unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if input is not really complicated:

```
 sed ": loop s/\('[^']*[^\\]\)\"/\1\\\\\"/;t loop;s/'/\"/g" input_file
```